# Перевод строки в BitArray и BitArray в строку

Tags: c#, bit

Я пишу методы расширения для перевода массива битов в строку и обратно. Однако не совсем пойму где именно у меня ошибка...

```
    public static class BitArrayExtention
    {
        public static string GetString(this BitArray array, Encoding encoding)
        {
            byte[] data = array.ToByteArray();
            return encoding.GetString(data);
        }
        public static byte[] ToByteArray(this BitArray array)
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[(int)Math.Ceiling(array.Length/8.0)];
            array.CopyTo(data,0);
            return data;
        }
    }
    public static class StringExtention
    {
        public static BitArray GetBitArray(this string s, Encoding encoding, int totalBits = 0)
        {
             BitArray ba = new BitArray(encoding.GetBytes(s));
             ba.Length = totalBits;
             return ba;
        }
    }
```

Проблема заключается в том, что когда я тестирую перевод битов в строку и обратно, то результат искажается, однако если тестировать перевод строки в биты и обратно биты в строку, то все осуществляется корректно. Подскажите где именно я мог ошибиться ?

```
        var encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();

        BitArray arr = new BitArray(new bool[] {true, false, false, true, true, true, false, true, false, true, false, false, true, true, true, false, true});
        PrintBA(arr);
        string s = arr.GetString(encoding);
        BitArray newArr = s.GetBitArray(encoding,arr.Length);
        PrintBA(newArr);


        s = "This is my test string";
        BitArray test_s = s.GetBitArray(encoding,s.Length*16);
        string restored_s = test_s.GetString(encoding);

        Console.WriteLine(s);
        Console.WriteLine(restored_s);
```

UPD:

---

Переделал метод копитования титов в байтовый массив так что бы кол - во битов на момент копирования было кратным восьми. Все равно результат не совпадает:

```
        public static byte[] ToByteArray(this BitArray array)
        {
            int size = (int)Math.Ceiling(array.Length/8.0);
            byte[] data = new byte[size];
            BitArray tmp = array.Clone() as BitArray;
            if(tmp.Length < size * 8)
            {
                tmp.Length = size * 8;
            }
            tmp.CopyTo(data,0);
            return data;
        }
```

Comment: Количество битов (булов) некратно 8.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov К сожалению не помогло. Хотя выглядит логично, раз строка конвертируется верно... В вопрос добавил свои изменения в коде.

Comment: Когда биты конвертируются в байты, теряется информация о первоначальном количестве битов. Нужно эту информацию как-то сохранять отдельно.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Не совсем Вас понял ,на каком именно шаге ? Когда в массив 
 байтов конвертирую или же когда из строки в биты ? Просто когда из строки в биты, я передаю кол - во битов нужных мне и обраезаю массив битов если жто нужно.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Интересно, но тесты показали, то конвертация успешла если массив битод не превосзодит 8. Если равно или более 8, то начинаются разногласия.

Comment: Вот смотрите: было 7 битов. Они конвертируются в 1 байт. Конвертируем обратно - получаем 8 битов. Появился один лишний. Его нужно отсечь. Для этого нужно запомнить первоначальное количество (7) и потом результат усечь до этого значения.

Comment: Кстати. Я до этого код особо не смотрел. Сейчас глянул. `encoding.GetString` - результат сильно зависит от кодировки. Если на вход подать массив байтов с мусором - результат будет непредсказуем. Не всякая последовательность байтов является корректной для UTF8, UTF16 и т. п. То есть нельзя просто так создать массив булов и пытаться конвертировать его туда-сюда.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Вот тут у меня видимо и кроется проблемма. Проверил вручную все пошагово, именно на момнте где в строку преобразую, разногласия начинаются.